# How to load view and return value to another function in controller codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller, view, codeigniter-3

I am new to codeigniter,I need to load a view and also return value to another controller.How to make it

here is my controller

```
function test1 {


  $value=  $this->input->post('value1');
  //some code 
   return ($result)
  $this->load->view('test');

}

function test2 {


  $resultvalue= $this->test1;

   echo($result);
          //some code 


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this code.

```
function test1() {
 $value=  $this->input->post('value1');
 //some code 
 $data =$this->load->view('test','',TRUE);
 return ($data)
 }

 function test2 {
    $resultvalue= $this->test1;
    echo resultvalue;
      //some code 

}
```

You need to set TRUE the third parameter while loading the view to get data(HTML) of view.
Hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use these methods

1. [Codeigniter Session](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html)
2. [Codeigniter Cookie](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/cookie_helper.html)
3. [Codeigniter Global variable](https://www.formget.com/codeigniter-global-variable/)

---

As your question I suggest you to use Session.

**Adding Session**

```
$this->session->set_userdata('result', $result);
```

**Retrieving Session**

```
$this->session->userdata('item');
```